# How to fix new node modules installation problem?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, deployment, netlify

I have my app which works just fine. But as soon as i run `npm install` or install new modules my signup stops working. Also when i deploy the app on `netlify` from `github`, it fails my signup.

This is the code block that i get error on, but i guess the code has nothing to do with this. its just that continuous deployment or installing new modules into the app fails. Signup only uses `firebase` module so i tried downgrading/upgrading it but that doesn't work either.

```
    if (   
           this.props.firebase.auth.currentUser 
        && this.props.firebase.auth.currentUser.userProfile 
        && !this.state.userProfile) {
      this.setState(
        {
          userProfile: this.props.firebase.auth.currentUser.userProfile.userProfile
        }
      );
    }
   }
```

Comment: How did you find out that running `npm install` is causing the signup to stop working? Do you change something in the node_modules folder to make it work again?

Comment: @ThomasvanBroekhoven I have a copy of old node_modules so if i want to make it work instead of running `npm install` i drop that folder in my app's source code. then it starts working.

Comment: Do you also have a copy of the package.json? You might see a difference in there too.

Comment: downgrading the `firebase` dependency version from 7.2.2 to `4.13.1` solved the continuous / `github` deployment problem. However when i add another module for example `npm install sib-api-v3-sdk --save` crashes my signup.